# SQL : Conditional query on several rows

Tags: sql

I have a table like

```
letter | number
a      | 1
a      | 1
b      | 2
c      | 1
c      | 2
c      | 2
```

and I would like to write a SQL query that only returns rows corresponding to letter values that are associated with both a number '1' and a number '2', i.e. I want to keep only

```
c | 1
c | 2
c | 2
```

from my example above.

Can anyone help? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Group By` and `Having` clause

This will give you the `letters` that are associated to number `1` and `2`

```
SELECT * 
FROM   yourtable 
WHERE  letter IN (SELECT letter 
                  FROM   yourtable 
                  WHERE  number IN ( 1, 2 ) 
                  GROUP  BY letter 
                  HAVING Count(DISTINCT number) = 2)
```

- **[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/910ca/3)**

If you want to find the `letters` that are associated **only** to `1` and `2` then use this

```
SELECT letter 
FROM   test 
GROUP  BY letter 
HAVING Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN number = 1 THEN 1 END) = 1 
       AND Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN number = 2 THEN 1 END) = 1 
       AND Count(DISTINCT number) = 2
```

- **[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce417/4)**

Comment: Thank you very much, but I forgot to mention that my table has many different possible 'number' values, and I want to keep letters for which both 1 and 2 appear, while other numbers may also appear. Any idea?

Comment: @Wajsbrot - Am checking for only 1 and 2 so it should work even if your table has other numbers]

Comment: Ok, I just fully understood your answer. It solves my problem, thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately when I use this query with Hive I get the following error : FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10249]: Line 5:6 Unsupported SubQuery Expression 'master_uid': Correlating expression cannot contain unqualified column references.

Comment: Do you have any idea why?